# Why is this mysqli_stmt_num_rows function returning 0?

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am trying to create a login page, but I'm having some issues using prepared statements to secure the login. I have the following code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_email=?";
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_prepare($db, $sql);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $email);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
$result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
$resultCheck = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt);
```

The problem occurs when checking if the result check variable is less than 1. It shouldn't be 0, but it is. I don't understand why, as the database has an email with the value `test@test.com`, but when trying to enter that the `$resultCheck` variable still returns 0. I'm guessing it has to do with the prepared statements.

Comment: a simple query can return a result in mysql or not?

Comment: Please check the only use comment in the manual page and verify whether it applies to your case.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález What?

Comment: I mean documentation. The official documentation. http://php.net/mysqli_stmt_num_rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client has no idea how many rows are in the result until they are fetched.

You can make the client pre-fetch all rows of the result by using [mysqli_stmt_store_result()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.store-result.php). Then you can use num-rows.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_email=?";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($db, $sql);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $email);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
$resultCheck = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt);

echo "result num_rows = $resultCheck\n";
```

This echo correctly produces the answer "1".

But if you do use store-result, for some reason you can't also use get-result. So you can't use result methods like fetch_assoc — you have to bind_result into variables by reference and use fetch().

By the way, mysqli_stmt_prepare() takes a statement object as its first argument, not the `$db` connection. Whereas mysqli_prepare() takes a connection object. Again, a confusing usage of mysqli functions.

---

I don't like mysqli. It's hard to use and has confusing traps of inexplicable behavior. I don't like how bind_param and bind_result make my code seem cluttered.

I prefer using PDO. It's much easier.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_email=?";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([$email]);
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
$rowCount = $stmt->rowCount();
```

Comment: I don't though.

Comment: Well that's a pity. You'll just have to deal with the confusing mysqli behavior I described in the first half of my answer.